# How do I use XL Data Tables with XLOOKUP for Data Validation

Tags: excel, validation, datatable, xlookup

I have a data table based on a query -> tblPrimaryProducts

tblPrimaryProducts has many columns, some of which are Category, SubCategory and Item.

If I were to use a filter on Category I would of course be able to see the SubCategories and Items in that Category. Likewise if I were to apply a filter to SubCategory in turn I would see a list of on the items in that specific Category + SubCategory selection. Ultimately this is the goal of data validation I am trying to implement.

There is a data entry table -> tblPackages

tblPackages has many fields, but importantly the three listed above need to be implemented in a controlled way via data validation so that each row can have the correctly selected Category + SubCategory + Item

I am unable to change the data table into an array or simple (or dynamic) named range because it will be refreshed any number of times and the column positions will potentially alter. This means that I have to use the table based naming system for both tables.

What I have so far is the following for a data validation formula using XLOOKUP:

```
XLOOKUP([@[Primary Category]] & [@[Primary SubCategory]], tblPrimaryProducts[Category] & tblPrimaryProducts[SubCategory], tblPrimaryProducts[Item],,0)
```

[@[Primary Category]] and [@[Primary SubCategory]] are fields in the tblPackages data entry table. The other fields listed come from tblPrimaryProducts. So far I have entered data by hand to test this out.

In the XL Formula window (where you can 'see' what your formula is doing while you fill in the fields) this seems to work and provides the output expected.

When I try to implement this as data validation it complains about an error in formula. If I place an INDIRECT at the beginning I get the syntax error popup. I have had issues in the past with INDIRECT that have been solved with the careful use of quotation marks. I cannot seem to find a way here to do this.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might implement some data validation based off of a data table (as opposed to an array), or the query that the table is based on in this situation? Under normal circumstances I would use dynamic named ranges but here I cannot.

Any help or ideas greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In Office365 the following formula will get you the list of "Items" that satisfy the "Category" and "Subcategory" conditions.

```
=FILTER(tblPrimaryProducts[Item],(tblPrimaryProducts[Category]=[@[Primary Category]])*(tblPrimaryProducts[Subcategory]=[@[Primary Subcategory]]),"")
```

It will give you a #SPILL! error if inserted in a Table and it returns multiple items that match the two criteria. You may have to redesign your output table.

If you are intending to display just the filtered values, you can then use two dropdowns with list of categories and subcategories. The filter function can then use these cells to filter the Items from source data and display as a list below.

Comment: Thankyou for having a go at this.

I understand what you have written, however it does not address the actual question. This approach yields exactly the same issue with using it as a source formula for data validation. It simply does not work as a data validation formula. It doesn't matter how it seems to be applied, exactly the same issues as my original attempts.

Can you suggest a way that I can implement this into data validation as a usable formula?